# How to call the database file in the subfolder?

Tags: php

This is the screenshot of my root folder.

[image]

I have a connection.php file on my root folder and I added the below code. I added the `BASE_URL` at the bottom.

```
<?php
$hostname = "localhost";
$username='root';
$password='';
$db='demo';


$charset = 'utf8mb4';
$options = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];
$dsn = "mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
try {
        $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        throw new PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());
  }
  
define('BASE_URL', 'http://example.com/');
?>
```

Now I have two files,

1. one is the `index.php` which is in the root folder and
2. second, I have a client folder that is in the root and inside the client, I have `list.php`

I have an issue with the connection.php file. I mean, I added `require('connection.php');` in the index.php which is working but if I add `require('connection.php');` in the `list.php` page then it's not working. It's not calling the `connection.php`.

I know it's a path issue and I can solve it like below code

```
require('../connection.php');
```

But I don't want to use a dot(../).

I tried the below code on my list.php page but both are not working.

```
1) require($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/connection.php');
2) require((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']";'connection.php');
```

Comment: @Luuk, I think, you have to check the duplicate question. I don't want to use a dot(../) because I have multiple subfolder.

Comment: @Luuk, I hope you know the meaning of __DIR__.  For example, if I am on root_folder->test->test1.php and If I add require(__DIR__'/connection.php'); then I will get the path like /opt/lampp/htdocs/no-data-test/test/connection.php which is totally wrong. my connection file is on the root folder

Comment: What exactly do you not like about `require '../connection.php';`? The file you are trying to load is one directory up, when you start your php script at `client/list.php`.

Comment: @Progman, I have to add the connection.php file on my all the pages. So  If I have to run the test1.php which is inside emp->create then what path I have to use for connection.php?

Comment: To get from `emp/create/test1.php` to the `connection.php` file in the root directory, you use `require '../../connection.php';`.

Comment: @Progman, Yes. My boss, Doesn't want that dot(../). He said, Use some path like require(http://example.com/connection.php). Because folder structure will change. So is there any other way to do?

Comment: You can use an absolute path, based on the root directory which you define somewhere. Then you can use something like `YOUR_APPLICATION_ROOT.'connection.php'` as the absolute path to the `connection.php` file.

Comment: @Progman, I tried 3 solutions which two of them are already added to the question. The third one is require(BASE_URL.'/connection.php'); all are not working.

Answer (score 0):

You cant try this, (as I understood to your needs, it works)

```
$path = __DIR__;
$path = chop($path, "/client");
$path .= "/connection.php";
echo $path;
```

Comment: I am getting like /opt/lampp/htdocs/no-data-testconnection.php

Comment: '/' add this one before connection.php (as I edited in the answer)

Comment: this returns to the full path to wanna go

Comment: I have multiple subfolders. I just shared the example folder "client". According to your code, I have to add your code in all the files and I have to change the folder name.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to access the `connection.php` file from the web application root directory, even after moving the PHP scripts to other directories and without changing the source code of these files, you can use an absolute path to that file. When you have

```
require '/opt/lampp/htdocs/no-data-test/connection.php';
```

in your PHP script it fill load the file from that exact absolute path. Even when you move your PHP script to different directories as in

```
/opt/lampp/htdocs/no-data-test/
/opt/lampp/htdocs/no-data-test/client/
/opt/lampp/htdocs/no-data-test/emp/create/
```

it will still find the correct location of the `connection.php` file. The down side is that you have an absolute path, with all the problems it comes with. When you deploy your application and it is not in `/opt/lampp/htdocs/no-data-test/` anymore, you have to update all the PHP scripts to the new path.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but still I am confused about what link I have to use in this require('../connection.php');. Do I need to use like this require('/opt/lampp/htdocs/no-data-test/connection.php');.?

Comment: @user9437856 When the file is located at `/opt/lampp/htdocs/no-data-test/connection.php` then you write `require '/opt/lampp/htdocs/no-data-test/connection.php';` to load the file in your PHP script.

Comment: after uploading the code on the server then what path I have to use it? https://example.com/connection.php this is the path

Comment: @user9437856 The path depends on the server. You have to ask the system administrator what the webroot path of your website is. You can use `var_dump(__DIR__);` to get an idea what it looks like. The path to the file will **NOT** begin with `http://` since you are not accessing the file via a HTTP request.

Comment: I tried var_dump(__DIR__); on my index.php page and I got this output string(54) "/home/u886461564/domains/example.com/public_html/no-data-test . So do I need to use like this require '/home/u886461564/domains/example.com/public_html/no-data-test/connection.php';

Comment: @user9437856 It looks correct. But you could simply try it. It will tell you when the file couldn't be loaded.